# What would my slack status show when minimized to system tray/notification area?

Tags: slack

What would my slack status show as when it is minimized to my Windows system tray?

I have the option **Leave app running in notification area when the window is closed** selected. So when I close the slack window, I still see the notification area icon for slack.

At this time, what would my colleagues see my online status as? I know that if I were to quit the app, then I would show up as offline, but what would my status show up as when the notification area icon is still present?

Answer (score 2):

Online; as long as you remain active on the computer.

From [this help article](https://slack.com/intl/en-au/help/articles/201864558-Set-your-Slack-status-and-availability#:%7E:text=Slack%20automatically%20determines%20your%20availability%3A%20you%E2%80%99re%20set%20to%20active%20when%20Slack%20is%20open%20on%20your%20desktop%20or%20mobile%20device.%20You%E2%80%99re%20set%20to%20away%20after%20ten%20minutes%20of%20desktop%20inactivity%20or%20if%20you%20navigate%20away%20or%20close%20the%20app%20on%20your%20mobile%20device.)

> Slack automatically determines your availability: you’re set to active when Slack is open on your desktop or mobile device. You’re set to away after ten minutes of desktop inactivity or if you navigate away or close the app on your mobile device.

The "navigate away or close the app" part only applies to mobile users.

Comment: Based on _"navigate away or close the app"_ statement; I'd assume that I'm marked as "inactive" immediately on navigating closing or navigating away from the mobile app. But with the desktop app there is a time delay after I close slack on the desktop. Also, I'm assuming that selecting **Leave app running in notification area when the window is closed ** means that the slack is open, and hence I would appear online.